# Why are flags limited

Tags: discussion, flagging

I tried checking flags everyday and they increase to 10 everytime  Why are the flags in Ubuntu are limited to 10 and do they get updated every day?? Or there is any limit to flags like 10 flags/day??

Comment: I bet it's so you can't abuse the flagging system... :P   What exactly do you want more than 10 flags for?

Comment: @ThomasW. I am just asking as if you got some more than 10 duplicate questions in front of you what will you do?? wait another day?? and Isn't it reasonable to ask about Community things..and this is one related to same

Comment: I just did post it as an answer :P  I'm way ahead of you.

Comment: @ThomasW. -I am a wayyy behind you as I am very young in rep and in experience also..and stop teasing me ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The low limit for people who don't have a billion helpful good flags to their record is probably an anti-abuse thing.

Ultimately, when you get higher up in your rep, you get the ability to cast Close Votes rather than Flags.  [You should look at the Privileges page](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges) for info on that, at 3000 rep, which you gain by asking good questions and posting good answers, close votes replace the "duplicate" flags, and are counted separately from flags.  But as you're a low-rep person, you're stuck with flags, and until you have a lot of good helpful flags, your limit won't go up very quickly.

If I remember correctly, the more "helpful flags" you've cast, the more your flags limit goes up, but that requires you to do a lot of flagging over time.

Comment: NOTE: Your reputation number ***does not*** affect your flag limit.  Making helpful flags over time does.